# login with msn for java website

Tags: java, oauth, openid, msn

I am creating a website whichi have various login options like login with facebook, google, msn etc.. I need your help for login with msn. Basically what I want is that user will click on login with msn link and msn ligin page will open where user will enter his msn credentials and after successfull login java api will fetch his profile info like name, gender, date of birth etc, after successfull login on msn and fetching user's info user will be redirected back to my website which will popup his info that I fetched.
So I need some links and suggestions on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you wanted is either use Oauth or OpenId. There are various Java based library which will do the heavy lifting for you and all you need to do is to

### OAuth

1. Create redirect URL for authorization
2. Send the code you get when user authorize your application to get access_token
3. use the access_token to get the required information

There are lots of API which will give you start-up

### Oauth API's

1. [scribe-java oauth](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java)
2. [oauth.googlecode](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/)

for list of Oauth library refer to this page [oauth.net](http://oauth.net/code/).

### OpenID library

1. [jopenid](http://code.google.com/p/jopenid/)
2. [dyuproject](http://code.google.com/p/dyuproject/)
3. [openid4java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/)

For more details refer to [wiki.openid.net](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries)

Answer (score 0):

i am also doing similar project. My project is completed 70%. firstly,if you are following the oauth scribe you can download the zip from the following link

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

include the commons-codec jar in the class path.

first execute the examples given by scribe.

for every oauth provider there are a little changes you have to do (very less changes.)

steps are given here.

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/getting-started

if you are any problem you can message here. i will see...